# App sending requests on launch

Tags: ios

I have a request being built and sent on a button press. All of the functionality that I desire to happen, happens when I press the button. The downside and the purpose of this question, is to find out why the requests inside the button press are sent when the app is started for the first time.

The view that the button is on is my root view controller.

I am not sure what information would be pertinent, so please let me know if more would be helpful.

Best regards.

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the code that is being called unexpectedly and see what is calling it when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, it was because the selector was running on a separate thread. Once I took the application off of the background thread and back onto the main thread, the functionality ran as expected.